# How can I force a reference to cite multiple editors (Eds.) instead of a single editor (Ed.) in my bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I have a reference to TEI as a technical standard in my `references.bib` file. On the TEI website it states that `TEI Consortium` should be credited as editors (plural), however, Overleaf doesn't recognise that there are more than one editor for my citation.

```
@techreport{TEI,
  type={Standard},
  title={{TEI P5: Guidelines for Electronic Text Encoding and Interchange Version 4.3.0}},
  editor={{TEI Consortium}},
  year={2021},
  month={8},
  institution={The TEI Consortium}
}
```

This results in the following bibliography entry:

```
TEI Consortium (Ed.). (2021). TEI P5: Guidelines for Electronic Text Encoding and Interchange Version 4.3.0 (Standard). The TEI Consortium.
```

Instead of `(Ed.)` it should read `(Eds.)`. How can I force it to do so?

Comment: A first comment: Speaking for myself, It doesn't look like `@techreport` is an appropriate choice for the "publication" at hand. I'd employ `@online` or its alias `@electronic`. Second, I'd say that it's perfectly nonpedantic to change `editor={{TEI Consortium}},` to `auhor={{TEI Consortium}},`. After all, you've already identified the creator to a "corporate" rather than a human entity.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using APA-style referencing, which manages this string using the `apaeditorstrg` macro. One solution would be to add a check here to see if `editortype = {editors}`, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{sources.bib}
@techreport{TEI,
  type={Standard},
  title={{TEI P5: Guidelines for Electronic Text Encoding and Interchange Version 4.3.0}},
  editor={{TEI Consortium}},
  editortype={editors},
  year={2021},
  month={8},
  institution={The TEI Consortium}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{apaeditorstrg}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{#1}>1\OR\ifandothers{#1}}
       {\bibcpstring{editors}}
       {\bibcpstring{editor}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{#1}>1\OR\ifandothers{#1}}
         {\bibcpstring{type\thefield{#1type}s}}
         {\iffieldequalstr{editortype}{editors}
             {\bibcpstring{editors}}
             {\bibcpstring{type\thefield{#1type}}}}}}

\begin{document}

\autocite{TEI}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting bibliography with plural marker for editors]